# Login loop Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia

I've installed ubuntu on a clean hardrive, everything went okay with the installation process, my laptop is acer aspire 5736z which didn't support nvidia drive!! After installing it and rebooting my laptop stuck on a login loop! Any solutions?

Comment: Use the open one.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If the closed proprietary driver does not work, just use the open source driver `nouveau`.

Comment: OK, but how can i do that?

Comment: Uninstall the `nvidia` ones. <kbd>Cltr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, login with your credentials, then `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nvidia*`, then reboot with `sudo reboot` and you should be ready to go! :)

Comment: I did that, now i got in but there's no side bar! Just the wallpaper!

Comment: So the problem that you posted is solved? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I am using AMD Radeon GPU driver. For me purging of the newly installed driver worked.

Press

alt+ctrl+F3

Login with your username and password

Then try

```
sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"
```

Then remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

I hope this will solve the problem

Comment: In place of fglrx put your driver's name